# Non blocking connect in Linux

Tags: c, linux

I use the function `connect` in Linux. If it can not connect, it will always be waiting to connect. What I want to do:

- Try to connect
- If success, it will be blocked.
- If not, it will try to connect for two hours
- If after two hours it has not succeeded in connecting, it will stop trying and no longer block.

How should I do this?

Part of my code:

```
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(_params->port);
_log.debug("connecting ...");
int co = connect(_socket,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));
if (co < 0) 
{
    return false;
}

_log.debug("connected ");
```

Comment: You could arrange for a signal to be sent when a timeout is reached by e.g. `alarm()` or `timer_create()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this has been answered before:
Use
    socket(..., SOCK_NONBLOCK, ...)
to create the socket.